# I am facing issue while installing phpMyAdmin for web hosting instance?

Tags: cloud, web-hosting, alibaba-cloud

After updating the host address, username and password in config.default.php, I tried to access phpMyAdmin via http://xxxx.aliwebs.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php. 
I get the following error message: "No input file is Specified"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `http://xxxx.aliwebs.com/phpMyAdmin/`. This will redirect to the default page
BTW, what environment you are using LAMP/LEMP?

If you are using LAMP try this:
`sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

add this line somewhere
`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

and finally restart apache.
`sudo service apache2 restart`